# Call the class in ignited codeigniter library from jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

i use ignited codeigniter library (datatable server side). the problem i can't call the class name from the button in jquery. the button not detected in jquery.
by the way the response from ignited codeigniter is json.

this is my ignite code in model:

```
$this->datatables->add_column(
    'opsi',
    '
        <span class="sc-product-item">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="$1">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="$2">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="$3">
            <input type="number" name="product_quantity" value="1" min=1 class="form-control" style="width:100px">
            <button class="sc-add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Tambah</button>
        </span>     
    ',
    'product_id, name, sale'
);
```

and this is my jquery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.sc-add-to-cart').click(function(){ alert('Hai'); });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: your question is unclear? can you explain a bit more? what problem you are facing?

Comment: Sorry. i have edited my question. My problem is, i can't call the class in jquery that send from ignited datatables. @AlivetoDie